# Google sheets formula to fill a cell only if the content in another cell is matching a particular word

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with raw data, let's call it "raw". I want to filter data based on the content in 1 cell and move the data in another sheet with a name "data". Basically, if one cell in the "raw" sheet says "yes" I want to move another cell's content to the "data" sheet.
Appreciate your help as I totally messed up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include a demo sheet and the things you have tried to make it easier for people to help you.

=FILTER(raw!A1:G, raw!B1:B="yes")

This should work for what you want, change the B column to the column you have "yes" in and change the A1:G to the data you want to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
=QUERY(raw!A:B; "where B = 'yes'"; 0)
```